# Error con dropdown menu(no se desplega)

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Estoy utilizando el tema flatly de bootstrap para crear una web.[Tema Flatly](https://bootswatch.com/flatly/)
El caso es que he puesto una navbar y hasta ahí todo bien peró al poner un elemento desplegable no se desplega y cuando la pongo en modo movil el boton desplegable tampodo se desplega.

Adjunto el código que tengo. Suponiendo que tengo los css en una carpeta css i los javascript en una carpeta js.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <title>Formulari de contacte</title>
     <!--link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


 </head>

 <body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Germans Climent</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item dropdown show">
                      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="categories" aria-expanded="true">Categories <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="categories">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Default</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cerulean</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cosmo</a>
                      </div>
                    </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Productes especials</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="ofertes.html">Ofertes</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="noticies.html">Noticies</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Ajuda</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Cercar</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="inisessio.html">Iniciar sessió / Registrar-se</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Comandes</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Cistella</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Tengo descargados e insertado jquery y bootstrap en las carpetas mencionadas anteriormente.

Espero su ayuda.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Me respondo yo solo porque JS i HTML nunca dejaran de sorprenderme xD

El caso es que como podeis apreciar en mi codigo cargo primero bootstrap y luego Jquery. Se ve que esto da problemas porque Bootstrap no puede leer los datos de Jquery. Al cambiar el orden de los scripts y poner primero el de jquery se soluciona.

Link a la referencia donde he visto la solucion.

> http://www.forosdelweb.com/f53/problema-bootstrap-dropdown-1143699/

Un saludo.

Comment: En Chrome puedes abrir el dev tools presionando F12, en la pestaña Consola, te apareceran los problemas relacionados con sintaxis, etc, eso ayuda mucho al momento de depurar.

Answer (score 1):

Respecto al error que te da Bootstrap, a mi no me da problemas con los siguientes enlaces:

**CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**JS**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Por otro lado, el navbar no te funciona por que `data-target` apunta a un id que no existe. No tienes ningun `#navbar01`.

Por ello debes cambiar la línea 20 con un id válido:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#idDeMiNavbar" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
```

Y a su vez dar un id al div:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="idDeMiNavbar">
```